# One query that gets many results for one "cell" and i want to spread them on multiple columns instead of one column

Tags: mysql

Here's the query i'm using

```
SELECT 
t1.name AS product_name,
t1.description AS product_description,
(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1) AS product_category,
(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 2) AS product_category2, 
(SELECT t2.name from table2 order by name ASC LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 3) AS product_category3 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
table3 t3
ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id INNER JOIN
table2 t2
ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
;
```

The tables i'm using have the following information:

```
table1: product_id, name, description

table2: category_id, name, description

table3: product_id, category_id
```

and i get this result

```
    name  -   description   -  category

    NAME 1 -  Description 1 -  Category 1


    NAME 2  - Description 2 -   Category 1
```

What i'm aiming for is the following result:

```
    name  -   description   -  product_category -category2 - category3

    NAME 1 -  Description 1 -       Cat1        -  Cat2    -   Cat5
    NAME 2  - Description 2 -       Cat7        -  Cat9    -   Cat11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have preferred to see some actual data, but one thing about your query that stands out is that you are including the `product_id` in your `GROUP BY` clause.  I don't think it belongs there, and you should not need it.  Instead, just group by the name and description.

```
SELECT
    t1.name AS product_name,
    t1.description AS product_description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS product_category
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3
    ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
GROUP BY
    t1.name,
    t1.description;
```

One explanation for why you were originally getting a single row is that the `product_id` serves as something like a primary key in `table1`.  In this case, you were effectively telling MySQL to group around individual records.  This would mean that `GROUP_CONCAT()` would only act on single records, leading to your current output.

Comment: Thank you for the advice ill keep that in mind, do you happen to know how i could return the nth result?? like for example if a query will get me 5 results, how do i tell sql to get the fifth result ? @Tim Beigeleisen

Comment: Yes, look into using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: sure thing man, i have a question though, i have edited the query please help me as its still not working.

Comment: You changed your query and it looks suspicious now.  You should either edit the question and provide a minimal sample data or open a new question.

Comment: I have changed the query i believe i have explained it better now. @Tim Biegeleisen